Troubles merging many rasters into worldwide map
I am trying to combine 267 flood hazard maps into one single global layer in QGIS. While trying this with the raster>miscellaneous>Merge function I needed 250gb of space even though the combined storage needed is only around 8gb total for the 267 layers. I tried this on someone else's computer and it took 15 hours or so. The output was an all black map that seemed to have put a 0 as a value of every pixel in the world except the flood areas which were normal.
I tried not specifying "no data value" or setting them to "NULL" but both resulted in a potential 250GB+ or bigger output which i cant do on my laptop. I thought combining raster data that didn't overlap into one map would be easy but I'm kind of at a loss here on how this works. Anybody got any ideas? (I'm kind of new to QGIS.)

Are the original rasters compressed? Have you specified a compression in Merge?

I would use Raster - Miscellaneous - Build Virtual Raster instead.

You can also try Mosaicking from the SAGA QGIS extension. Sometimes it is more efficient.

I how do i know if my origional rasters are compressed? they are unzipped im pretty sure.

I tried building virtual raster but it also needs a huge storage space. Im not sure why it does that :(

Rasters are, well, rasters. All pixels must be stored, and all take up space. Some image formats support compression, so repeating values take less space, but it's still not no space. So a global raster at high pixel density would be expected to be large.

To see if it is compressed: Double-click the layer - Information - Compression

What is the data type of the original rasters (Properties->Information->Data type)? And what data type have you selected when you run Merge?
